# ImageMagick, How to edit an image from S3 server using gm library

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick and gm, how to use an image from S3 server instead of 'test.jpg', it works fine with images in locale pc, but not with S3 server

```
     gm('test.jpg')
        .resize(200, 200)
        .stream('jpg', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
            stdout.pipe(res);
        });
```

But when I use the S3 image url it doesn't work

```
gm(full image url in S3 server)
    .resize(200, 200)
    .stream('jpg', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        stdout.pipe(res);
    });
```

I tried also to read it as stream

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(full image url);
    gm(readStream)
        .resize(200, 200)
        .stream('jpg', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            stdout.pipe(res);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
var request = require('request');

gm(request(full_url_to_s3_image), 'test.jpg')
    .resize(200, 200)
    .stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
        stdout.pipe(res);
    });
```